# How to compare and lookup one list with another list?

Tags: python, list, compare

I have 2 lists - one holds `int values and the other string. I am iterating through the list to find the highest value in it and once I do I want to lookup the corresponding name for that highest value. I am reading my data from a csv file that has 2 columns: month and amount.

```
monthSales = []
totalSales = []

for col in sale:
    monthSales.append(col['month'])
    totalSales.append((col['sales']))
print('Month: ', monthSales)
print('Sales: ', totalSales)
print(max(totalSales))
print(min(totalSales))
```

this gives the following output

```
Month:  ['jan', 'feb', 'mar', 'apr', 'may', 'jun', 'jul', 'aug', 'sep', 'oct', 'nov', 'dec']
Sales:  ['6226', '1521', '1842', '2051', '1728', '2138', '7479', '4434', '3615', '5472', '7224', '1812']
```

I can get the highest and lowest values using max and min but I want to be able to extract the associated month with it and display that along with the value.

so for example using above: highest sales is 7479 which is in month July. so how do i display both this values?

any help appreciated

I have managed to get max and min sales but just need guidance on how to do a secondary lookup for the corresponding list associated with the sales list

Comment: Note that your `max` and `min` calls only work because all your `totalSales` numbers have four digits. String comparison uses [lexical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographic_order), so this will fail if all strings are not of the same length

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get the index of max values in list and then print the values from another list with max's index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70138256/how-can-i-get-the-index-of-max-values-in-list-and-then-print-the-values-from-ano)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just make one list of tuples, and then call `max` or `min` with the key argument to use the sales number:

```
sales = [(col['month'], int(col['sales'])) for col in sale]
print(max(sales, key=lambda x: x[1]))
print(min(sales, key=lambda x: x[1]))
```